# .htaccess modify with different name files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have links:

```
mydomain.com/index.php
mydomain.com/index.php?cat=1
mydomain.com/index.php?product=1
mydomain.com/index.php?view=content
mydomain.com/pages.php?view=order
mydomain.com/pages.php?view=register
mydomain.com/price.php
```

When I enter this links in browser, must get content from that files:

```
index.php.html
index.php_cat=1.html
index.php_product=1.html
index.php_view=content.html
pages.php_view=order.html
pages.php_view=register.html
price.php.html
```

How can I modify .htacces file for all this links?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteEngine on
# general
RewriteRule  ^index.php.html$  index.php 
RewriteRule  ^pages.php_view=register.html$  pages.php?view=register
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php\.html$ /index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^price\.php\.html$ /price.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php_([^=]+)=([^.]+)\.html$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [NC,L]
```